# expand/collapse a record view using JSF1 - tomahawk implementation

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

can any one help me how to do with expand/collapse view of a record using JSF1 - tomahawk implementation.
I found in few blogs that this can be done with 'varDetailToggler' attribute of  tag. but not seen any implementation/usage of achieving the purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find a demo on tomahawk examples. Here is some links where you can find the information you want: [Master-Detail with Ajax and JSF 2.0](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/tomahawk/trunk/examples/simple20/src/main/webapp/masterDetailAjax.xhtml) ----- [Master-Detail with JSF 1.1/1.2 and JSP](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/tomahawk/trunk/examples/simple/src/main/webapp/masterDetail.jsp). You can download tomahawk assemblies with the examples [HERE](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you brief me how does this varDetailToggler="detailToggler" work ? Apart from the JSP page is there any need for the Java Bean action method to be implemented ?                                                       I could see the JSP file. Have tomahawk in place. The link to the example repository is not working.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the links.

Comment: I wanted to use the 'expandAllDetails()' function with the varDetailToggler. When doing this I do not want all my rows to have 'Hide'/'Show' kind of actionlinks . I just need a single hyperlink attached to the 'varDetailToggler' that toggles the record view of the dataTable. Can you thorw me some light how to achieve this in my dataTable ?